# RHEL 6.5 to 6.4 downgrade error

Tags: linux, redhat, downgrade

I was following a RHEL [solution](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/186763) about the downgrade, which went as follows:

1. Check [version and releases](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/3078)
2. search for the available packages

   yum list kernel-2.6.32-358*
3. Install the rhel 6.4 kernel package yum install kernel-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6
   .... Complete !
4. Reboot system
5. Clean up

   yum clean metadata
    yum clean all
6. Now downgrade

   yum -y downgrade redhat-release
7. I get the following error
     Downloading Packages:
     https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/6Server/x86_64/os/Packages/redhat-release-server-6Server-6.4.0.4.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
   Trying other mirror.

The current 6.5 is clean install not upgrade and I was not able to find a way to configure 6.4 repositories ... Also the changes in any of the grub files : 
      /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.conf
      /etc/grub.conf
      /etc/grub.conf.rpmsave

and reboot according to [this instruction](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/1321) do to cause the server to boot into 6.4 's kernel ... and it did not work neither ...

Search for loading of the kernel without reboot , yet it seemed too risky ... 
This [hack](http://korovamilky.tumblr.com/post/16460518079/running-new-linux-kernel-without-rebooting) gave just before the latest command EFI related errors , so did not apply it ( do not want to go to the data center ... yet ... )

So after some 5 hours of googling the following questions arose:
When one buys RHEL 6.5 subscriptions is it the case that downgrade is not even possible
or 
Is it possible, but first RHEL 6.4 repos must be configured ( how ?! Should RH Customer Support be contactd ?! )

and am I completely lost about some fundamentally basic link missing to resolve this issue ?!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade your RHEL installation?

Comment: It is part of bigger software dependency matrix ...

Comment: Is there something specifically in EL6.5 that's incompatible with your environment?

Comment: The software vendor of the product I am installing on RHEL does support  max RHEL 6.4

Comment: There are very few cases where software won't work on minor revision upgrades in RHEL. I'd push back with the vendor.

Comment: Can't push back IBM ;O)

Comment: I did with Oracle... Find out what the incompatibility is, and work with it. You can't keep EL6.4 forever.

Comment: You can't even keep 6.4 _today_ sometimes: the OpenSSL is vulnerable to Heartbleed, for instance, and most third party software requires you to update to 6.5. You _can_ push IBM on this, and you _should_ push them _very hard_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running anything other than the latest release of your major version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux is not supported unless you have also purchased an [Extended Update Support](https://access.redhat.com/site/support/policy/updates/errata/#Extended_Update_Support) subscription for the server.

You can set your preferred release level [using the `subscription-manager` tool](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1/html/Quick_Registration_for_RHEL/preferred-os.html). There is no supported way of doing this if you registered with the legacy RHN.

```
[root#server ~]# subscription-manager release --set=6.4
[root#server ~]# yum distro-sync
```

Comment: Thans for the fast answer ... :
subscription-manager release --set=6.4
'exceptions.ValueError' object has no attribute 'msg'

Comment: Something strange is going on with your installation. I would suggest you contact Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks again ;o) I just re-run the commands and this time with success !!! 
  subscription-manager release --set=6.4
Release set to: 6.4
 root@datnode3 [Mon May 26 01:13:45] [~] $
 yum distro-sync
....
Installed:
  redhat-release-server.x86_64 0:6Server-6.4.0.4.el6

Complete!
  cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Comment: ... and prevent any future undesired upgrades : 
grep 'exclude=kernel*' /etc/yum.conf
exclude=kernel*

Comment: @yordangeorgiev Blacklisting kernel upgrades that way is also a bad practice. You will have undesired effects down the road.